# How to make div disappear when window width is reduced?

Tags: html, css, fixed, graphical-logo

I am trying to make my logo stay fixed on my header.  Here is my example site: http://www.hidesertheat.com/test/index.html

When the window is expanded to a certain height the logo (The sun) changes position. How can I make it fixed?

Also I want the logo to disappear after a certain point of the window is reduced. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css media queries. [read examples here](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: I currently already have css media queries. I am just unsure on how to make the sun logo not be displayed after the browser goes to a smaller size.

Comment: .headerlogo_tag {display: none;}

Comment: Also do you know how to make the logo remain fixed? I dont want it to go past the home tab when the screen size is adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setheight(){

var sliderheight = window.innerHeight - jQuery(".header").height();

liheight = sliderheight;

sliderheight = sliderheight+"px";

jQuery("div").css({"dispaly":"none"});

}
```

See the above example , It may help you